# Trick to remove the sticky header space on the top

Tags: html, css

I'm "fighting" with a problem since some years and I haven't find an "elegant solution" to remove the space created by the sticky header.

Usually is not a problem, so you don't have "the problem" but unsolved problem one day or another will come.

Why the problem happen? Having hero section with images I would like to give a transparency to the header, and this will give to me a with area between the top of the page and the content.

The only one trick I found is give a negative margin of the same heigth of the header bar, and this "solve the problem" but is just like hide dirt under the carpet.

Sincerely I don't understand why this happend, If the z-index is a layout system I don't understand why the header space is reflected to the main page.

I've tried to give the z-index 0 to the body, but this don't helped me.

Any solution different from mine one??

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://codepen.io/stefanotesla/pen/oNGPbMG

Comment: What is the negative margin you added? I'm curious to see the desired result because I am confused by the explanation.

Comment: Check now, is better with an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your header to be fixed at the top of the page, you can consider `fixed` instead of `sticky`.

Check [this](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/KKXxzaM).

Comment: I would like the header stay there when page is scrolling so fixed is not the answer, but can be usefull Thanks

Comment: Im afraid that the negative margin could be the easiest trick you can do.

Comment: Fixed also makes the header stay when the page is scrolling.

Comment: Wow... I checked it now!! It's fantastic!! Thank you so much